# Detect double spaces at start of sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, subprocess

If a sentence starts with double spaces, I need to neglect that line and check with other lines. If it doesn't, I need to print that line. I am newbie to python, please help me out with this.

Comment: *"`startswith` double spaces"*. There is a *hint* in your question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty simple. You can check if the first char of the string is . See below example

```
sentences = ['  this wont print', 'this will print', "   this wont print either", " this will print"]
for sentence in sentences:
    if sentence.startswith('  '):
        print(sentence)
```

Comment: sorry my bad. I updated it for double space.

Comment: This really helped me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the first two characters of the string S using `S[0:2]` and check if it is equal to   double spaces `'  '` or not.
`if (S[0:2]=='  '):`